# Problem deleting an element in the DynamoDB table with secondary index

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm stuck because I'm having a problem deleting an element in DynamoDB table with primary key and global secondary index (there is no Sort Key).

I get the following error:
***"The provided key element does not match the schema"***

I am desperate, I also tried to look at the answers of other posts on this site but I could not find anything about the delete.

This is my code:

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  let body;
  let statusCode = 200;
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "DELETE",
  };

  try {
    switch (event.routeKey) {
      case "DELETE /fragments/{id}":
        await dynamo
          .delete({
            TableName: "fragment",
            Key: {
              id: event.pathParameters.id
            }
          })
          .promise();
        body = `Deleted fragment ${event.pathParameters.id}`;
        break;
       default:
        throw new Error(`Unsupported route: "${event.routeKey}"`);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    statusCode = 400;
    body = err.message;
  } finally {
    body = JSON.stringify(body);
  }

  return {
    statusCode,
    body,
    headers
  };
};
```

Comment: And the partition key is “id”?

Comment: @hunterhacker Yes exactly

Comment: Is the `id` key's DynamoDB data type `String` or `Number` (or `Binary`)?  Is the key's type consistent with `typeof event.pathParameters.id`?

Comment: @fedonev The data type of id is `number`. It is consistent with typeof `event.pathParameters.id`

Comment: @fedonev I am stuck for this reason. Could the secondary index be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**   Convert `event.pathParameters.id` from `string` to `number` type.

```js
// convert id from string to number
Key: { id: parseInt(event.pathParameters.id, 10) }
```

`DynamoDB.DocumentClient` [infers the key schema types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html) from the javascipt types in `Key`.  `event.pathParameters.id` is a string, but your key schema expects a number, so DynamoDB returns a schema mismatch error.

How do we know `event.pathParameters.id` is a `string`?  The [lambda typings for API Gateway events](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/aws-lambda/trigger/api-gateway-proxy.d.ts) tell us so:

```js
// APIG event pathParameters
export interface APIGatewayProxyEventPathParameters {
    [name: string]: string | undefined;
}
```

Comment: perfect, thank you infinitely. After several days of "fighting" this was the problem